# Type Traits and const/volatile/&/&&

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

When you write a trait class using partial template specialization, say

```
template <typename> class Foo {};

template <typename T>
struct is_instance_of_foo : std::false_type { };

template <typename T>
struct is_instance_of_foo<Foo<T>> : std::true_type { };
```

when the type is not exactly `Foo<...>` but some `const` / `volatile` / `&` / `&&` qualified version of `Foo` the trait would evaluate to false. Is it good practice to use `std::decay` to strip these qualifiers?

```
template <typename T>
using is_instance_of_foo2 = is_instance_of_foo<std::decay_t<T>>;
```

Or is it expected that `is_instance_of_foo<Foo<char> const &>::value` is false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say this really depends on the desired semantics (equivalently: intended use) of the trait. In some contexts, you might want to cover everthing "based" on `Foo<T>`, in other contexts, only `Foo<T>` itself is what you're after.

Going by the name alone, I would probably use `std::remove_cv` as the wrapper. A `const Foo<T>` is still an instantiation of `Foo`. A `Foo<T> &` is most definitely *not*—it's not even a class type, it's a reference.

Comment: I was also thinking about a forwarding reference: if `template <typename T> void bar(T &&) {...}` is called with some instance of `Foo`, `T` may be deduced to `T &`, `T const &`, `T` or (unlikely) `T const`. If I wanted to check Foo-ness using `T` alone, it could be useful to have it report true for `Foo<...> const &`.

Comment: @MadScientist When doing non-trivial work with forwarding references, you pretty much have to always use `std::remove_reference` anyway (for other standard traits, initialisers etc.). So having it done automagically by one trait could actually be inconsistent at best and harmful at worst (makes you forget it where it's required).